# Why so bad the performance of the NodeJS object creation if num of props greater than 8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, performance-testing

I would like to know that there are any limit in NodeJS when create an object which has more than 8 properties? I made a benchmark test and it seems if the object has more than 8 properties, the performance will be bad.

Test suite: https://github.com/icebob/js-perf-benchmark/blob/master/suites/properties.js (full copy at end of question)

**The result:**

- Create object with 1 prop             0%     (62,695,620 rps)   (avg: 15ns)
- Create object with 8 prop        -31.95%     (42,662,752 rps)   (avg: 23ns)
- **Create object with 9 prop        -95.79%      (2,640,046 rps)**   (avg: 378ns)

**Code:**

```
bench.add("Create object with 8 prop", () => {
    let opts = {
        prop1: 5,
        prop2: "",
        prop3: false,
        prop4: 1,
        prop5: 0,
        prop6: null,
        prop7: "Hello",
        prop8: 12345
    };
    return opts;
});

bench.add("Create object with 9 prop", () => {
    let opts = {
        prop1: 5,
        prop2: "",
        prop3: false,
        prop4: 1,
        prop5: 0,
        prop6: null,
        prop7: "Hello",
        prop8: 12345,
        prop9: "asd"
    };
    return opts;
});
```

**Environment:**

- Windows_NT 6.1.7601 x64
- Node.JS: **6.9.5**
- V8: **5.1.281.89**
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4

---

Here's the content of the linked test suite above:

```
"use strict";

let Benchmarkify = require("benchmarkify");
let benchmark = new Benchmarkify("Object properties").printHeader();

let bench = benchmark.createSuite("Create object with many properties");

// ----

bench.add("Create object with 1 prop", () => {
    let opts = {
        prop1: 5
    };
    return opts;
});

bench.add("Create object with 8 prop", () => {
    let opts = {
        prop1: 5,
        prop2: "",
        prop3: false,
        prop4: 1,
        prop5: 0,
        prop6: null,
        prop7: "Hello",
        prop8: 12345
    };
    return opts;
});

bench.add("Create object with 9 prop", () => {
    let opts = {
        prop1: 5,
        prop2: "",
        prop3: false,
        prop4: 1,
        prop5: 0,
        prop6: null,
        prop7: "Hello",
        prop8: 12345,
        prop9: "asd"
    };
    return opts;
});

bench.add("Create object with 20 prop", () => {
    let opts = {
        prop1: 5,
        prop2: "",
        prop3: false,
        prop4: 1,
        prop5: 0,
        prop6: null,
        prop7: "Hello",
        prop8: 12345,
        prop9: "asd",
        prop10: false,
        prop11: 5,
        prop12: "",
        prop13: false,
        prop14: 1,
        prop15: 0,
        prop16: null,
        prop17: "Hello",
        prop18: 12345,
        prop19: "asd",
        prop20: false
    };
    return opts;
});

bench.run();
```

Comment: Well-asked, interesting question. I moved the test suite into the question, since links rot.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know - yes.

Object in v8 engine has two object representations:

- fast with limited amount of props
- slow with unlimited props

For new objects V8 engine allocates memory for "FAST 8 properties object" by default which should cover most use cases.

If the amount of properties exceeds this limit - it rebuild object into more SLOW form, but which allows to have unlimited amount of props inside.

By the way this doesn't related to the new object instantiation (like `new X()`):
Time from time V8 engine recounts amount of props for new objects(per class/internal type). So if your code creates complex classes - engine will start to create FAST objects with more properties by default for this class/internal type.

---

PROOF:

The details about memory management for V8 engine can be found here http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation

For the new object constructed without a class (like `var a = {}`) - all properties go to fixed array, called in article "Extra properties"

Engine allocates space for [8 elements in fixed array by default](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.h#L3430)

After fixed array is full - object is [rebuilt into dictionary here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.cc#L3663)

Prototypes and system objects are always FAST, they use different [rebuilding procedure](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.cc#L3448) when fixed array is full.

Comment: added a proof... spent few hours on investigating this. Please correct me if my proof is wrong... i'm a quite new in C :-)

Comment: Great links. You should quote the relevant bits **in** the answer as links rot. Also, the Jay Conrod blog entry dates from 2012 (updated 2013); V8 has moved on a fair bit in four years, it may or may not still be valid. But heck, congrats on even finding the right source file, I get seriously lost in the V8 source (having not had a week to spend studying it...after brushing up my 20-years-out-of-use C++ skills). Massive +1 one here.

Comment: Seriously impressive answer - I would have never guessed V8 did this, my first thought was that the testing methodology was somehow flawed.  Very nice find!

Comment: *"Prototypes and system objects are always FAST"* I think you mean "Objects created via constructor," not prototypes, there. Prototypes are just objects. Interestingly, not only is creating 9+ prop objects with a ctor is much faster than using a literal (for reasons you indicated), creating one using `Object.create(prototypeWithAllTheProps)` and then assigning the props to the obj is faster than a literal too (but not as fast as the ctor), which is odd given that the object still has to have the props created in it (shadowing its prototype's copy of them). https://pastebin.com/mPrnaULS

Comment: @AndreyMuzalevsky Nice job! Very detailed answer. It would be good a small page on nodejs site about this "limitations"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks your pastebin. I updated my benchmark suite. Big difference between raw object & constructor.